# Getting Parameter value in CDK

Tags: java, aws-cdk

I have the following code for CDK:

```
CfnParameter serviceContainerPort = new CfnParameter(
                parent,
                "ServiceContainerPort",
                CfnParameterProps.builder()
                        .withType("Number")
                        .withDescription("The port at which your service is listening.")
                        .build());

ContainerDefinition container = taskDefinition.addContainer(....

container.addPortMappings(PortMapping.builder()
.withContainerPort(serviceContainerPort.getStringValue())
                .build());
```

So, above the problem is, I have a parameter defined as serviceContainerPort which is of type CfnParameter. Now, I wanted to use this reference of parameter in the container.

withContainerPort() accepts a Number type but I don't know how to get the Number type from serviceContainerPort.

In case, it accepts a string, it works perfectly fine. But in this case, it is not. Any idea how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

For AWS CDK in Java, you could do

```
serviceContainerPort.getValueAsNumber()
```

to get the Number type value.